# There were , between { li }

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to display an array using DOM. The problem is that I get ',' between LI elements. How can I delete that?

```
const boresult = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-function"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};

function makeList(arr) {
  const resultDisplayArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    resultDisplayArray.push(`<li>${arr[i]}</li>`);
    // resultDisplayArray.push('<li style="color: red">' + arr[i] + '</li>');
  }
  return resultDisplayArray;
}

// document.getElementById('ba').innerHTML = makeList(boresult.success);
const resultDisplayArray = makeList(boresult.success);
document.getElementById('ba').innerHTML = resultDisplayArray;
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Use `resultDisplayArray.join('')`

Comment: Sometimes an example is worth a thousand words: `["a","b","c"].join()` gives `"a,b,c"`, `["a","b","c"].join("")` gives `"abc"`, `["a","b","c"].join("|||")` gives `"a|||b|||c"`. Got it?

Answer (score 1):

You could join the array with an empty string.

If you take just the array and the environment expect a string, then the `toString` method is called, which is basically the same as [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), but it takes a default string of `,` for joining.

To prevent this, you need to take an own parameter.

```js
function makeList(array) {
    return array.map(v => `<li>${v}</li>`);
}

const boresult = { success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-function"], failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"], skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"] };

document.getElementById('ba').innerHTML = makeList(boresult.success).join('');
```

```html
<ul id="ba"></ul>
```